# Assert name field of registration process with sendKeys java selenium

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, testng, assert

I have an automation running on a website with registration process.
I need to assert all fields on registration: name, email, pass, confirmPass.
If for example I run my test as follows it always fails since the Actual always remains empty. what am I missing here with the sendKeys ?
***InsertXpathAndClick
InsertIDAndKeysToSend
etc are shortcuts to find elements and click or send keys (they operate as expected on other parts of my program)***

```
  @Test
    public void TestAssertName() {
        SingeltonDriver.driver.navigate().to("https://buyme.co.il");
        SingeltonDriver.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        SingeltonDriver.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        InsertXpathAndClick("//*[@id=\"ember676\"]/div/ul[1]/li[3]/a/span[2]");
        InsertXpathAndClick("//*[@id=\"ember650\"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/p/span");
        SingeltonDriver.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);


//This is the interesting part of checking the name val that i sent VS the one that i get by getText.

        InsertIDAndKeysToSend("ember1179", "Kate");
        WebElement ActualName = SingeltonDriver.driver.findElement(By.id("ember1179"));
        String ActualNameUpdated = ActualName.getText();
        Assert.assertEquals("Kate", ActualNameUpdated);
    }
```

Comment: we need the code snippet for the failing code like 'InsertIDAndKeysToSend'

Comment: public static void InsertIDAndKeysToSend(String ID, String KeysToSend) {
        SingeltonDriver.driver.findElement(By.id(ID)).sendKeys(KeysToSend);
    }

Comment: can you also paste the HTML snippet?

Comment: @user3581800 : On the target URL you want to click on registration and then click on to register on the pop up opened. Then you want to enter the first name? Correct me if you want to do something else.

Comment: Use `String ActualNameUpdated = ActualName.getAttribute("value");` instead.